# PHP register not working

Tags: php, mysql, registration

Here's my code

```
  <?php
include("config.php");
$title=$_REQUEST['sel1'];
$fname=$_REQUEST['t1'];
$lname=$_REQUEST['t2'];
$gen=$_REQUEST['r1'];
$id=$_REQUEST['t3'];
$pass=$_REQUEST['p1'];
$phone=$_REQUEST['t5'];
$add=$_REQUEST['t6'];
$city=$_REQUEST['t7'];
$coun=$_REQUEST['t8'];
$dob=$_REQUEST['t9'];
if($_REQUEST['sub'])
{
$sel=mysql_query("select id from register where id='$id' ");
$arr=mysql_fetch_array($sel);

if($arr['id']!=$id)
  {
   if(mysql_query("insert into register values('$title','$fname','$lname','$gen','$id','$pass','$phone','$add','$city','$coun','$dob')"))
       {

         echo "<script>location.href='index.php?con=13 & wel=$id'</script>";
       }
     }
else 
{
echo "user already exists";
}

}
?>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function fnam()
{
  var fnam=/^[a-zA-Z]{4,15}$/;
   if(document.f1.t1.value.search(fnam)==-1)
    {
     alert("enter correct  first name");
     document.f1.t1.focus();
     return false;
     }
    } 

     function lnam()
{
  var lnam=/^[a-zA-Z]{4,15}$/;
   if(document.f1.t2.value.search(lnam)==-1)
    {
     alert("enter correct last name");
     document.f1.t2.focus();
     return false;
     }
    } 

function email()
{
 var email=/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]+@[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
   if(document.f1.t3.value.search(email)==-1)
    {
     alert("enter correct email");
     document.f1.t3.focus();
     return false;
     }
    } 

    function pass()
    {
    var pass=/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]{6,16}$/;
   if(document.f1.p1.value.search(pass)==-1)
    {
     alert("enter correct pass");
     document.f1.p1.focus();
     return false;
     }
     }
    function phone()
    {
    var phn=/^[0-9]{9,14}$/;
  if(document.f1.t5.value.search(phn)==-1)
    {
     alert("enter correct phone no");
     document.f1.t5.focus();
     return false;
     }
     }

    function add()
    {
    var add=/^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]{10,150}$/;
  if(document.f1.t6.value.search(add)==-1)
    {
     alert("enter correct address");
     document.f1.t6.focus();
     return false;
     }
     }

     function city()
     {
     var city=/^[a-zA-Z]{5,30}$/;
     if(document.f1.t7.value.search(city)==-1)
    {
     alert("enter correct city");
     document.f1.t7.focus();
     return false;
     }

     }
      function coun()
     {
     var city=/^[a-zA-Z]{5,30}$/;
     if(document.f1.t8.value.search(city)==-1)
    {
     alert("enter correct country");
     document.f1.t8.focus();
     return false;
     }

     }

function vali()
{
  var nam=/^[a-zA-Z]{4,15}$/;
   var email=/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]+@[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
    var pass=/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]{6,16}$/;
        var phn=/^[0-9]{9,14}$/;
      var add=/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{10,150}$/;
      var city=/^[a-zA-Z]{5,30}$/;

   if(document.f1.t1.value.search(nam)==-1)
    {
     alert("enter correct  first name");
     document.f1.t1.focus();
     return false;
     }

  else if(document.f1.t2.value.search(nam)==-1)
    {
     alert("enter correct last name");
     document.f1.t2.focus();
     return false;
     }

  else if(document.f1.t3.value.search(email)==-1)
    {
     alert("enter correct login name");
     document.f1.t3.focus();
     return false;
     }



   else if(document.f1.p1.value.search(pass)==-1)
    {
     alert("enter correct pass");
     document.f1.p1.focus();
     return false;
     }


      else if(document.f1.t5.value.search(phn)==-1)
    {
     alert("enter correct phone no");
     document.f1.t5.focus();
     return false;
     }


  else if(document.f1.t6.value.search(add)==-1)
    {
     alert("enter correct address");
     document.f1.t6.focus();
     return false;
     }




    else if(document.f1.t7.value.search(city)==-1)
    {
     alert("enter correct city");
     document.f1.t7.focus();
     return false;
     }

        else if(document.f1.t8.value.search(city)==-1)
    {
     alert("enter correct country");
     document.f1.t8.focus();
     return false;
     }

     else 
    {
     return true;
     }
     }


</script> 
</head>
<body>


<div><br/><center><h2><font face="Lucida Handwriting" size="+1" color="#00CCFF">Register Yourself</font></h2></center></div>
<div>
<div style="width:25%;float:right">
<br><br><br><br><br>
<img src="usepics/7.jpg">
</div>
<br><br>
<center><div style="width:70%;float:right" align="center">
<fieldset style="background:#CC99CC;width:50%">
<br><br>
<form method="post" name="f1" onSubmit="return vali()">
<table width="366" border="0" align="center">

  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"><strong><font size="+1" face="Comic Sans MS">Title:</font></strong></div></td>
    <td><label>
      <select name="sel1" id="sel1">
        <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
        <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
        <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
      </select>
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="164"><div align="center"><font size="+1" face="Comic Sans MS"><b> First&nbsp;Name:</b></font></div></td>
    <td width="192">

        <input name="t1" type="text" id="t1" onChange="return fnam()">    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"><font size="+1" face="Comic Sans MS"><strong>Last name:</strong></font></div></td>
    <td><input name="t2" type="text" id="t2" onChange="return lnam()" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"><font size="+1" face="Comic Sans MS"><b>&nbsp;Gender:</b> </font></div></td>
    <td><input name="r1" type="radio" value="male">
      <strong>Male</strong>
        <input name="r1" type="radio" value="female">
        <strong>Female</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"><font size="+1" face="Comic Sans MS"><b>&nbsp;Enter Email : </b></font></div></td>
    <td><input name="t3" type="text" id="t3" onChange="return email()"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"><font size="+1" face="Comic Sans MS"><b>&nbsp;Choose a  Password:</b> </font></div></td>
    <td><input name="p1" type="text" id="p1" onChange="return pass()"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> <td><div align="center"><font size="+1" face="Comic Sans MS"><b>Phone no: </b></font></div></td>
    <td><input name="t5" type="text" id="t5" onChange="return phone()"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"><font size="+1" face="Comic Sans MS"><strong>Address:</strong></font></div></td>
    <td><label>
      <textarea name="t6" id="t6" value="return add()"></textarea>
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"><font size="+1" face="Comic Sans MS"><strong>City:</strong></font></div></td>
    <td><input name="t7" type="text" id="t7" onChange="return city()"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"><font size="+1" face="Comic Sans MS"><strong>Country:</strong></font></div></td>
    <td><input name="t8" type="text" id="t8" onChange="return coun()"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"><strong><font size="+1" face="Comic Sans MS">Date of Birth: </font></strong></div></td>
    <td><label>
      <input name="t9" type="text" id="t9">
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><label><br>
    <center>
      <input name="sub" type="submit" id="sub" value="Create my Account">
    </center>
    </label></td>
    </tr>

</table>
 </form>
</fieldset>
</div>
</center>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Whenever I click the create my account button the page refreshes and nothing is added to the database. The database name is shop, here's the config code used to connect to it.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("shop");
?>
```

and here's the welcome page code that should execute if the registration is successful.

```
<html>

<div>
<div style="width:25%;float:right">
<br><br><br><br><br>
<img src="usepics/7.jpg">
</div>
<br><br>
<center><div style="width:70%;float:right" align="center">
<div><br/><center><h2><font face="Lucida Handwriting" size="+1" color="#00CCFF">Welcome User</font></h2></center></div>
<br><br><br>
<fieldset style="background:#CC99CC;width:50%">
<br><br>
<font color="#660033" size="+1" face="Comic Sans MS"><b>You are Successfully Registered!!! </b></font><br/><br/>
<font size="+1" face="Comic Sans MS" color="#660033" ><b>Your id is:</b><font color="#FF3366"><?php echo $_REQUEST['wel'];?></font><br/><br/></font>
</fieldset>
</div>
</center>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, debugging is as much part of being a programmer as actually writing the code is, for us to help you, you need to short down your code and locate the issue, as your question is now there's simply too much code and it's in danger of being closed.

Comment: What is your table structure?

Comment: <form action="#" method="post" name="f1"> try this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if($arr['id']!=$id)
  {
   if(mysql_query("insert into register     values('$id','$title','$fname','$lname','$gen','$pass','$phone','$add','$city','$coun','$dob')"))
   {

     echo "<script>location.href='index.php?con=13 & wel=$id'</script>";
   }
 }
```

Mention id in values

Comment: He did, you now have it twice.

Answer (score 0):

If you have php 7, then:
"This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension should be used."

More on this: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php